# How can I use mail() with redhat, I can't send mail

Tags: php, email, sendmail, redhat, postfix-mta

I am experiencing a problem since a week....
I installed a redhat web server 6 and I upload my file. It work but nor the form.
When I want to send a form, I got this error message :

```
object(SocketException) {
    [protected] _attributes => array()
    [protected] _messageTemplate => ''
    [protected] _responseHeaders => null
    [protected] message => 'Could not send email.'
    [protected] code => (int) 500
    [protected] file => '/var/www/step/lib/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php'
    [protected] line => (int) 76
}
```

The form use the mail() function of PHP.

I have no idea, what should I configure on my redhat web server to let him send e-mail.

The ports smtp, www, ssh are open

I also install postfix but it did not solve my problem.

Someone know what can I do?
Should I installed something and how to configure it?

Many thank for your help in order to use the function mail()

Answer (score 1):

"fatal: chdir /var/spool/postfix: Permission denied" can be solved with:

**setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1**

See: http://chirale.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/apache-centos-6-cannot-send-email/

Comment: Yes, I already solve my problem like this. You were faster than me by providing the solution. Cheers

Comment: httpd_can_sendmail --> on

Answer (score 0):

Try FIRST with this mini script and let me know the results:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it does work as well. No mail are receive to the recipient. $to has my private e-mail and cc has my prof e-mail. No e-mail has been received yet.

Comment: With unbuntu I solve that issue by installing postfix, but on redhat, it did not solve any think. I think the solution us not postfix, but I am really not sure

Comment: Make sure PHP PEAR is present on the server else install it:
[root@localhost ~]#yum install php-pear
and install PHP Mail extension using PEAR:
[root@localhost ~]#pear install Mail and restart Apache service

Comment: Hello, I also did it. #yum install php-pear and then #pear install Mail, and it did not solve my problem

Comment: if you send mail with my script, can you show me the error line(s)?

Comment: There is no error displayed with you script. If I have an error with my scrupt it because my framework as an exception and display the error of the frame work. But I observer an information into the log : "fatal: chdir /var/spool/postfix:". See below.